# How to adjust the y axis ticks of R barplot to be not uniformly (not evenly spaced)

Tags: r, plot, axis

How to adjust the y axis ticks of R barplot to be not uniformly (not evenly spaced), just like the following figure.

[image]

UPDATE: we are going to draw a figure as follows:

[image]

Comment: Should it be in log scale?

Comment: Boy.... it certainly appears to be on a log10 scale. Post a complete example and a better description.

Answer (score 5):

```
x <- c(2, 5, 15, 30, 70)
barplot(x, axes = FALSE)
axis(2, at = x)
box()
```

[image]